# input tooltop plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am looking for a plugin that displays something like tooltip that I can put html inside.
Something like a datepicker were I have a little image that allows me to open a helper that will assist fill the input.

Do you know such plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery Tooltip Plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/) has worked well for me, including with forms:

```
$('#myImage').tooltip({ 
    delay: 0, 
    showURL: false, 
    bodyHandler: function() { 
        return $("<form><!-- Add form contents here --></form>"); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) is pretty good.

Only issue is you have to define the styles in the JavaScript (last time I used it at least).